# How to change the column order using Flex and a long text staying on the same line

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to put the pink column as below and that makes me crazy:

[image]

I found this example :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

but then the pink bloc goes under the orange bloc, and I would like to put it under the green bloc (like in the picture above)

Any idea ? is it possible (the green bloc can have any size) ?

Comment: Not possible with flexbox but without code it's hard to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a solution for the [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box orange"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box pink"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "orange green blue" "orange pink blue";
  column-gap: unset;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: orange;
  padding-top: 300px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  grid-area: green;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
  grid-area: pink;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: blue;
}
```